# Is there a ruby equivalent to the php __invoke magic method?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Is there an equivalent to the php __invoke method in ruby?

e.g

```
class Test {
    public function __invoke() {
        echo "invoked";
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$test(); // prints invoked
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the same exact thing but it should do the job

```
class Test
  def self.call
    puts "invoked self.call"
    return new
  end

  def call
    puts "invoked call"
  end
end

t = Test.()
t.()
```

You can use the `.()` syntax on both classes and objects, since classes are objects. `.()` is just a shorthand for `.call`